# C++ dot net error C 3265:cannot declare a managed ' ' in an unmanaged 'wmain::$unnnamedClass $0x43505982$383$

Tags: c++-cli

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    typedef struct
{
    String ^name_1;
    String ^Max_1;
    String ^Min_1;
}power_line_name;

    power_line_name * power_list[5];
    StreamReader ^ sr=File::OpenText("testcpp\\test\\powerline.txt");
    array<System::String ^> ^power_line;
    array<System::String ^> ^d_line;
    String ^ eachString;
    String ^ eachString_2;
    String ^ eachString_3;
    int i=0;
    try
    {
        String^ s="";
        while (s=sr->ReadLine())
        {
            //Console::WriteLine(s);
            power_line=s->Split(':');
            Console::WriteLine(s);
            for each ( eachString in power_line)
            {

                Console::WriteLine(eachString);
            }
            d_line=power_line[1]->Split('|');
            power_list[i]->name_1=d_line[0]->ToCharArray();
            power_list[i]->Max_1=d_line[1];
            power_list[i]->Min_1=d_line[2];
            i++;



        }
        Console::WriteLine(s);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(sr)
            delete (IDisposable^)(sr);
    }
}
```

error C 3265:cannot declare a managed 'name_1 ' in an unmanaged 'wmain::$unnnamedClass $0x43505982$383$

error C 3265:cannot declare a managed 'Max_1 ' in an unmanaged 'wmain::$unnnamedClass $0x43505982$383$

error C 3265:cannot declare a managed 'Min_1 ' in an unmanaged 'wmain::$unnnamedClass $0x43505982$383$
what can i do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a Native struct (power_line_name) with Managed members (name_1, etc...). In order to do this the Native struct must use the gcroot<> or auto_gcroot<> template.

ex.

```
    #include <msclr\auto_gcroot.h>
```

. . .

```
    typedef struct
{
    msclr::auto_gcroot<String^> name_1;
    msclr::auto_gcroot<String^> Max_1;
    msclr::auto_gcroot<String^> Min_1;
}power_line_name;
```

Later, don't use ->ToCharArray()

```
    power_list[i]->name_1=d_line[0]; // ->ToCharArray();
    power_list[i]->Max_1=d_line[1];
    power_list[i]->Min_1=d_line[2];
```

An alternative approach which would not need the gcroot stuff would be to make the struct managed like this:

```
ref struct power_line_name
{
    String^ name_1;
    String^ Max_1;
    String^ Min_1;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto power_list = gcnew array<power_line_name^>(5);
```

. . .

Comment: It seems compiler crashed. Severity Code 
Error C1001 An internal error has occurred in the compiler.